# Only some cover art showing on iPod Nano 4

Tags: ipod

All of my songs have cover art and it all shows on iTunes, but some of the songs' cover art do not show on my iPod Nano 4. It shows fine on iTunes, but when I am looking at it on my iPod, it doesn’t show.